# Flutter Pub Get

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

while pub get i reach this problem:

```
Because salut depends on flutter_block any which doesn't exist (could not find package flutter_block at https://pub.dartlang.org), version solving failed.
```

how can I resolve it?

Comment: add dependencies section of your **pubspec.yaml** file

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `flutter_block` package doesn't exist anymore on pub.dev, and therefore the maintener of the package `salut` need to push a new update of his dependency

If it's your package, you may have made a mistake between `flutter_block` and [`flutter_bloc`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)

Comment: TY ill try this